# Why is the product of homeomorphisms a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:A\to C$ be homeomorphisms, where $A,B,C$ are topological spaces. My book says that $(f\times g):A\to B\times C$ is also a homeomorphism.

I wonder why that is. Define $f,g:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ as $x\to x$. Clearly both $f$ and $g$ are homeomorphisms. Now take an open set $(0,1)\in\Bbb{R}$. Is the mapping $(f\times g)(0,1)$ also an open set? I am getting confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It isn't. It is a homeomorphism to a subspace of $B\times C$, however.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a typo in the book. The product $f\times g$ must be from $A\times A$, not $A$. Otherwise it is wrong. Take, for example, $A=B=C=\mathbb{R}$ with $f=g=id$. Then $\mathbb{R}$ is obviously not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think your example is more obvious if $A=B=C$ is a finite topological space, in which case they are not even in bijection. The "obviousness" of your statement actually requires some thinking (which is done pretty much everywhere in topology nowadays, but still), for instance by removing a point and observing fundamental groups.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Thanks, you are right! Finite spaces are even better!

Comment: it's also possible the book means it is a homeomorphism to the range of $f\times g:A\to B\times C$...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If $U$ is open in $B$ and $V$ is open in $C$ is $U\times V$ open in $B\times C$?

Comment: That shows the function is continuous. Not clear how it shows a homeomorphism.

Comment: Doesn't it come from the fact that $f$ and $g$ are homeomorphisms? It's continuous and sends open sets to open sets and since $f$ and $g$ are bijective, so is it's product.

Comment: The map $A\times A\to B\times C$ is bijective, but the question is about $f\times g:A\to B\times C$.